# Upper bound for exponential random variable

Tags: exponential-function

For $N>\mu>0$, I wonder how to show that

$$
\left(1-\frac {\mu}{N}\right)^{N-\mu}\geq e^{-\mu}.
$$

The only thing I know is

$$
e^{-\mu}\geq \left(1-\frac {\mu}{N}\right)^{N}.
$$

But I don't know how to derive the required inequality from this.